# Drawing on HTML canvas in wrong position - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having issues with my Javascript drawing about 300 pixels to the right and 100 pixels below where my cursor is located upon a draw event.

I've looked over several other similar questions trying different methods like `clientX/Y` but none have worked. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:

My canvas element:

```
<canvas id="can" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
```

These variables are initialized outside my functions:

```
var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
    prevX = 0,
    currX = 0,
    prevY = 0,
    currY = 0,
    dot_flag = false;

var x = "black",
    y = 2;
```

My init function:

```
function init() {

    canvas = document.getElementById('can');

    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    w = canvas.width;
    h = canvas.height;

    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
        findxy('move', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
        findxy('down', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
        findxy('up', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
        findxy('out', e)
    }, false);

}
```

Calculates where to draw:

```
function findxy(res, e) {

    if (res == 'down') {
        prevX = currX;
        prevY = currY;
        currX = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        currY = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
        console.log(e.pageX + " " + e.pageY);
        flag = true;
        dot_flag = true;
        if (dot_flag) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = x;
            ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
            ctx.closePath();
            dot_flag = false;
        }
    }
    if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
        flag = false;
    }
    if (res == 'move') {
        if (flag) {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            currY = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
            draw();
        }
    }
}
```

My Draw Function

```
function draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
    ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
    ctx.strokeStyle = x;
    ctx.lineWidth = y;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

Comment: a snippet might help in troubleshooting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be working as intended. I assumed at first it had something to do with the fact that your canvas wasn't at 0,0 of your screen but after testing that, it still worked as intended.

You'll need to provide more information regarding how you implemented these functions.

```js
var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
    prevX = 0,
    currX = 0,
    prevY = 0,
    currY = 0,
    dot_flag = false;

var x = "black",
    y = 2;


function draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
    ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
    ctx.strokeStyle = x;
    ctx.lineWidth = y;
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function init() {

    canvas = document.getElementById('can');

    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    w = canvas.width;
    h = canvas.height;

    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
        findxy('move', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
        findxy('down', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
        findxy('up', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
        findxy('out', e)
    }, false);

}

function findxy(res, e) {

    if (res == 'down') {
        prevX = currX;
        prevY = currY;
        currX = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        currY = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
        console.log(e.pageX + " " + e.pageY);
        flag = true;
        dot_flag = true;
        if (dot_flag) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = x;
            ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
            ctx.closePath();
            dot_flag = false;
        }
    }
    if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
        flag = false;
    }
    if (res == 'move') {
        if (flag) {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            currY = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
            draw();
        }
    }
}

init();
```

```html
<canvas id="can" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
```

Comment: So your answer led me to find the issue which was with bootstrap. I had to remove the canvas outside of the bootstrap container and all works fine now. Thanks